# Constrain whole window within desktop borders in OS X Lion

Tags: macos, desktop, window

Is there a way in OS X Lion to constrain my application windows to not pass outside the desktop borders?

I hate it when I drag a window away to take a look of a window that's underneath and when I come back, only half that window shows on the screen.

Maybe not a common feature request, but it would be very neat.

Answer (score 1):

No built-in way I know of, but you can just let a window management tool "snap" your windows to the screen's edge when you drag them there. This is similar to the "Aero Snap" feature Windows introduced.

[image]

Here are a couple of tools that do this:

- [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) (free, window snapping is an advanced feature)
- [BetterSnapTool](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580?mt=12) ($1.99, more options)
- [Moom](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/moom/id419330170?mt=12) ($4.99, nice app, many features)